# Convert string to datetime in local timezone Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, localtime

I have datetime in string needing to be converted in datetime format. Below is my code but it returns error. what I am missing here.

```
from datetime import datetime

LocalStartTime='2020-09-17T10:55:06.4000000+1000'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(LocalStartTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Required output shd be date converted in current timezone to format like: '2020-09-17 20:55:06' whatever will be the actual value.

returns below error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-09-17T10:55:06.4000000+1000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Comment: [dateutils parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) should be able to handle more than six digits of fractional seconds

Answer (score 3):

from datetime documentation:

> When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from **one to six digits** and zero pads on the right. %f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available).

you have one too many zeros in the float part after the seconds part.
the limitation is 6 digits.

```
from datetime import datetime

LocalStartTime='2020-09-17T10:55:06.400000+1000'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(LocalStartTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

should work

***Edit:***
after the OP edited and asked about converting to a different timestamp:

seems like what you're looking for is `timestamp()` and `fromtimestamp()`
you can get the timestamp which is a posix timestamp represented as float, and convert it back to `datetime` object with `fromtimestamp()` if you want to remove the float part after the seconds you can convert the time stamp to `int`.

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datetime_object.timestamp()))
```

Comment: ok, just noticed you changed the date my data is '4000000' 7 digits

Comment: @14578446 yes, and what I'm saying is that it's a bad input to the `datetime.strptime` function. see what is written in the documentation part. "* the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right. *"

Comment: @Daniel hmm i understand. I will have to work with bad data then. and can u tell how i can convert it to like time in current time zone. I have editied question accordingly.